# What is the HQL equivalent of this SQL?

Tags: nhibernate, hql

```
SELECT *
FROM [Group] g
INNER JOIN User2Group ug
    **on g.Id != ug.GroupId**
INNER JOIN [Activity] a
    on a.Id = g.ActivityId
WHERE g.UserId != 2
AND a.Lineage like '0,1,%'
```

Group > 1-n > User2Group < n-1 < User
m-n relationship

Activity > 1-n > Group
1-n

Trying to get all groups that a user has not already added to their account.

What I have so far:

```
var groups = repository.SimpleQuery<Group>("from Group as g join fetch g.Users as u join fetch g.Activity as a where g.Type != ? and a.Lineage like ? and g.CreatedBy.Id != ?", Group.GroupType.Deleted, string.Format("{0}%", lineage), currentUser.Id);
```

What has me tripped up is the "on g.Id **!=** ug.GroupID"

Comment: What I ended up with: var groups = repository.SimpleQuery<Group>(start, show, "from Group as g where g.Type != ? and g.Activity.Lineage like ? and g.CreatedBy.Id != ? and g.Id not in (select g.Id from Group as g join g.Users as u where u.Id = ?)", Group.GroupType.Deleted, string.Format("{0}%", lineage), currentUser.Id, currentUser.Id);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard when I don't see the entities and the mappings, but the

```
on g.Id != ug.GroupId
```

part could probably be expressed in HQL by

```
from Group as g where g.id not in (select u.group.id from User u where u.id = ?)
```

The rest of the where clause should be easy to add.

Mind that it's been a while since I worked with HQL :-)

Comment: I was trying a not in within Ayende's QueryBuilder and it wasn't working and didn't try it in HQL.  I went to SQL and got that going, but I think your HQL might also work.  I'll give it a try.  Thanks!